# NoSuchMethodError using Android Jack toolchain

Tags: android, retrolambda, jack-compiler, android-apt, jack-toolchain

I'm trying to enable Java 8 new language features by using Jack toolchain. I've removed retrolambda and android apt plugin from my Android Project but I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForAppDebug'.

> com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Just needed to add guava as a dependency on my build.gradle main file like classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'